# How can I perform different submit in HTML form with Delphi?

Tags: html, delphi

I'm writing a software to automatically fill fields in a TWebBrowser and make the related Submit.

Unfortunately, the form contains three buttons that perform different types of submit.

Clearly, this doesn't work:

```
form: = WebFormGet (formNumber, WebBrowser1.Document AS IHTMLDocument2);   
form.submit;
```

I spotted this line of code at the top of the HTML page:

```
<form name = "RicercaIMMForm" method = "post" action = 
"https://sister.agenziaentrate.gov.it/Visure/vimm/RicercaIMM.do" onsubmit = "this.scelta.disabled = true;">
```

and this at the bottom:

```
<td> <input type = "submit" name = "choice" value = "Search"> </td>
<td> <input type = "submit" name = "choice" value = "Visura"> </td>
<td> <input type = "submit" name = "choice" value = "Clean"> </td>
<td> <input type = "submit" name = "choice" value = "last search"> </td>
```

I should have submit the button with "Search" value.

...
...
...

Can you help me?

---

UPDATE 17/03/2020
I solved with this:

```
procedure TFMain.WebFormSubmit(const document: IHTMLDocument2;
  const formNumber: integer);
var
  Doc: IHTMLDocument2;
  WebForm: IHTMLFormElement;
  FormElements: OleVariant;
  i: integer;
begin
  Doc := WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
  WebForm := Doc.Forms.Item(0,'') as IHTMLFormElement;
  FormElements := WebForm.Elements;
  FormElements.Item(19).Click;
end;
```

`Item(19)` is the number of my object (in this case, the button)

Comment: You will have to enumerate the DOM to find the `<input>` element you want (such as by using `IHTMLDocument4.getElementsByName()` to get a list of the "choice" elements, then loop through that list querying their `value`s until you find "Search") and then call that element's `click()` method.

Comment: Thanks, I solved (UP).

Comment: Your update should have been [posted as an answer instead](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Please [edit] your question to remove it, and then post it as a proper answer.